# how to properly modelize an object with localized (i18n) properties

Tags: oop, data-structures, localization, internationalization

I have an Entity which has an id and a title. The id is always the same but the title value change given a locale. I found three way to modelize this :

```
class Entity
    String getId()
    String getTitle(Locale)
```

or

```
class Entity
    String getId()
    LocalizedEntity getLocalizedEntity(Locale)

class LocalizedEntity
    String getTitle()
```

or

```
class Entity
    String getId()

class LocalizedEntity extends Entity
    Locale getLocale()
    String getTitle()
```

I tend to prefer the first one because it does not corrupt the way you modelize the Entity, it is just a kind of view of your object. The second is the worst case for me.

Which one is better ? Is there another way ?

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, that your data are localised should not impact on your object design, so I would go with your first option.

We built a localisation engine in my day job, a few years ago, and that is the model we used, where the `Locale` object was specified with three properties ([ISO 639-1 α-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) language code, [ISO 15924 α-4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15924) script code and [ISO 3166 α-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) territory code, together making up an [IETF language tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag), like `en-Latn-GB`, `zh-Hans-CN`, `sr-Cyrl-RS` and so on).

I hope that helps, though I'm guessing you probably made your decision last year, given the date of your question.

Comment: Thanks, it helps for my ego because despite all my arguments, my boss choosed the second option. He's main argument was to provide a model without any duplicated data at all. So I wanted to confront my point of view here to know if I was right. One year and half after, I can tell it was the worst choice for the projet, and the enterprise :-/

Comment: Well, if I at least helped your ego, that's better than helping noone  :o)